# Restricting Child Domain Admins from installing software

Tags: active-directory, installation, sccm

I recently installed SCCM 1606 in my environment that contains a main forest/domain and has child domains. I got it all working, but what i'm looking for is restricting domain admins and users for all child domains from being able to install any program unless it's through SCCM or if the user is an Enterprise Admin, then only they can install programs. Is there a way to restrict that? I can't seem to find a way to stop domain admins from installing stuff.

Comment: Domain Admins members are administrators of the domain and can install software on any domain member machine. If you don't want them administering the domain or installing software on any domain member machines then remove them from the Domain Admins group.

Answer (score 4):

Domain Admins have rights to administer the domain and its constituent machines. If you try to remove those rights, you will have a bad day – and, in any event, the Domain Admin can reverse your change to grant themselves the privileges again.

If you don't want Domain Admins to have these rights, do not make then Domain Admins. If you want them to manage objects in Active Directory, use delegation of control.